# Calculate the limit: $\lim _{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

Calculate the limit:
$$\lim _{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i)}\right)$$

Comment: What, which terms cancel?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i)}=\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i}$.

Comment: Which terms cancel out?

Comment: I suggest trying a few examples, say with $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Comment: For $n=2$, we have $1-1/2+1/3-1/4$. I still don't see it.

Comment: Right, so the series is actually $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i}=\ln(2)$.

Comment: Oh! I didn't recognize it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{2n-2}-x^{2n-1}\right)\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2N}}{1+x}\,dx$$
where $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\color{red}{\log 2}$ and $0\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2N}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^{2N}\,dx = \frac{1}{2N+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{(2i-1)(2i)}
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2i-1}-\frac1{2i}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i}{i}\\
&=-\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^i}{i}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\log(1+x)\\[9pt]
&=\log(2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please explain how you got from the limit with partial fractions, to the limit with powers of -x? Also likewise for powers of -x to log(1+x)

Comment: I've added a step in attempt to address the first concern. The second concern is using the power series for $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Ok I now follow the second step onto the third, however I don't follow the first step onto your new 2nd

Comment: The second line is just a rewriting of the line above it; that is, the odd denominators have positive numerators and the even denominators have negative numerators. Try writing out the first several terms of each if it is still not clear.

Comment: Some user  'put on hold' the question after he answered the question. Is it a normal behaviour ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin: there is no precedent against it, but it seemed a bit odd to me, too.