# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)} = \ln(2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While proving some results on series I encountered that, one of those result  implies that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}$$
is convergent and it has sum equal to sum of alternating harmonic series.  (And we know that alternating harmonic series converges to $\ln2$.)

However I am not able to find the sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}$ directly (without that result). Is there is any way to show that sum equals to $\ln2$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}  = \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: @ArcticChar sir, then after that? I didn't get it. Since  $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ is divergent, how we can show sum is $ln2$

Comment: Write out the terms of the series using ArcticChar's hint. Does that suggest anything?

Comment: After the breakup  the series is identical to the alternating harmonic.  What else do you want?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here.  Are you confused about whey the alternating harmonic series converges to $\ln(2)$, or are you confused about how to rewrite the given series so that it is clearly the alternating harmonic series?

Comment: In either case, this question has been answered on Math SE before, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467382/, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716/ .

Comment: I thought the confusion is that the OP do not realize the factorization. Now I am not so sure (deleting answer, it's covered by another answer anyway)

Comment: This one, too (though it is closed, it has relevant answers): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903778/468350

Comment: @XanderHenderson sir, thanks for the links you provided.

Comment: @ArcticChar sir, thanks for the hint

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Your question is a duplicate of at least one of questions I've linked to above.  Can you please clarify *which* of the above answers your question?

Comment: @XanderHenderson sir, may be with first link in first of your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}$$
So the given sum is nothing but
$$S=(1-1/2)+(1/3-1/4)+(1/5-1/6)+(1/7-1/8)+.....+...$$
Now note that $$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+x^5/5+....$$
So $S$ nothing but $x=1$ case of the logarithmic series written above.
Therefor $s=\ln 2$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\ln2$$ Now what we do is part the sum  in even and odd parity  ie  when $n\to 2n $ and $n\to 2n-1$ .$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 1} \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} -\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}=\ln 2$$